# Make two lines of text the same width regardless of character count

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the second-line text to stretch to the full width of the first-line text. Is that possible? Meaning `cheap cars` would be written in the same width space that `washington` occupies.
Similarly, lets say I make the first-line text something short like `vegas`, then the second-line text would have to `shrink` to the width space that `vegas` occupies. Possible?

```css
.hello {
  width: 50%;
 }

.hello p {
 font-size: 40px;
 color: blue; 
}

.hello p span {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: red;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="hello" href="#"><p>WASHINGTON<span class="site-subtitle">cheap cars</span></p>
   </a>
```

Comment: `text-align-last: justify`, or if you need IE support as well, wrap each word in the subtitle in a span, and then use flexbox & `justify-content: space-between`

Comment: You can't magically change font size of the 2nd line so the width of its content will adapt to the width of the 1st line and not occupy a 3rd, 4th line (in CSS). The element can have the same width but that's all.

Comment: not sure why you would want that. You're best bet would be to have a container and have both line in separate divs inside the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, there is an easy way to do this. Set the [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) property to `justify-all` (or set [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last) to `justify`) and set [`text-justify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify) to `inter-character`. This should space out the characters on each line to fill the full width. However, browser support seems to be lacking at the time of this writing.

```css
p {
    text-justify: inter-character;
    text-align: justify-all;
    /* or */
    text-align-last: justify;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">
    Washington<br>
    Cheap Cars
<p>

<hr>

<p class="two">
    Vegas<br>
    Cheap Cars
<p>
```

However, even if this did work, you may not want the effect it would give:

```
V    e    g    a    s
C h e a p  c  a  r  s
```

The only other way around this would be to use a combination of `letter-spacing` and `font-size`, and manually tweak every instance of this pattern:

```css
p {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
}
p span {
    display:block;
}

.one span:last-of-type {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: .93em;
}

.two span:first-of-type {
    letter-spacing: 11px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">
    <span>Washington</span>
    <span>Cheap Cars</span>
<p>
<hr>
<p class="two">
    <span>Vegas</span>
    <span>Cheap Cars</span.
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a{
text-decoration: none;
  width: 50%;
 }

a p {
 font-size: 40px;
  line-height:0.6;
 color: blue; 
}

a p span {
 font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
 color: red;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#"><p>WASHINGTON<br><span>cheap cars</span></p>
   </a>
```